# Scheduler is Not Executing for Month

Tags: adempiere

I Scheduled a Process for all interval Hours,Week,Month.
It quite well for Hours,Week, but for **Month its not running.**
There is no log/error in Scheduler.
No customization its default adempiere code.

Can anyone please help me to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

> its default adempiere

Which version of the standard Adempiere?

I assume you are using the Schedule Type = Cron Scheduling Pattern.
What value did you enter for the cron pattern?

Adempiere uses cronj4 to manage the cron scheduler - Adempiere 3.8 is using cron4j 2.2.1 maybe check if it has any issues reported.

Comment: Schedule type  = Month DaY

Comment: They're not active by default in my 3.8 version!  Perhaps because they have bugs? :)

Comment: Month Day is works in My est Box my problem is not in LIVE

Comment: The Month/Day options are there in the default 380 but they've not been enabled in the AD.  I assume for a reason.  Have you tried using the cron type schedule as it can be configured for monthly running too - and I expect it does work!